# How did the first vampire come into existence?

Tags: hellsing

The question is simple. What is the origin of these vampires? Where did they come from? How did the first **PURE** vampire come into existence?

Answer (score 1):

The oldest known vampire is alucard. He came to be a vampire by drinking the blood of the fallen from a battlefieled thus dropping his belief in god and turning into an unholy creature.

Comment: Any canonical mentions or links would be appreciated!

Comment: This is from memory somewhere in the manga towards the end of it chapter 70-80 i think.